# permutation representation of the symmetric group $_$ and its trace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups, characteristic-polynomial

I have this algebra task which I have encountered problems with proving a specific identity for,

> Consider the permutation representation of the symmetric group $_$, which gives a group homomorphism $\rho : _ \to (\mathbb{C}^n)$ and is defined by $$ \rho()_=_{()}, $$where $_1,…,_$ are the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

I'm asked to show that $tr(\rho())$ is equal to the number of $ \in \{1,…,\}$ such that $()=$.

I would appreciate any helps in this regards as I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: It is not clear what the connection is between the things you've said regarding the characteristic polynomial and the rest of your quesiton

Comment: There should be $\rho(g)v_i=v_{g(i)}.$ The trace is equal $$\sum_i \langle \rho(g)v_i,v_i\rangle =\sum_i \langle v_{g(i)},v_i\rangle$$ This proves the claim as $\langle v_{g(i)},v_i\rangle =1$ if $g(i)=i$ and $0$ otherwise.